# how to set the background color for draw text?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I want to set the background for text, which means that I want to set the color of the rectangle contains the text. I have tested QPainter.setBackground, but it do not work. This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumHeight(200)
        self.setMinimumWidth(200)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)
        pos = QPoint(50, 50)
        painter = QPainter(self)

        brush = QBrush()
        brush.setColor(QColor(255,0,0))

        painter.setBackgroundMode(Qt.OpaqueMode)
        painter.setBackground(brush)

        painter.drawText(pos, 'hello,world')

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = MyLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I want is:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to implement a personalized QLabel, it is enough to set the background color through Qt Style Sheet, also do not use a layout if you want to establish a certain position

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("hello,world", self)
        self.label.adjustSize()
        self.label.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: {};".format(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0).name())
        )
        self.label.move(QtCore.QPoint(50, 50))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: just curious here why do you not put the window.resize( ) call within the initialization routine of Window as  self.resize( ) ??  Is it not better to keep all the elements of a class self contained unless absolutely necessary to do otherwise?  Also why include sys.argv if you do nothing with it?

Comment: @DennisJensen That's a matter of taste, so being inside or outside is not against any design principle.

Comment: @DennisJensen You can pass sys.argv or list() or [], follow the same principle, on the other hand I have the bad/good habit of using sys.argv since sometimes I want to pass other flags, like for example in Qt WebEngine allows me to enable the remote debug, or I can also point to the style or the qss without the need to modify code

Comment: hmm keeping things encapsulated within themselves is a sort of good design principle the last time I looked ;)   As for sys.argv implementing something you are not going to use within a function for any reason is a bad habit actually as it just adds in unnecessary complexity that could lead to confusion -- like now why did he include that, it does not seem like he is using it but maybe I am wrong and I just have not found where he is using it -- that kind of thing

Comment: Note I only mention this because often folks come here and then adopt the habits (good or bad) of those that supply answers and it seems a disservice to me to share answers that have bad elements to them if one knows better not to kind of thing

Comment: @DennisJensen I understand it, but there are bad habits that I propose in my answers for example: my way of importing, the best would be "from PyQt5.FooModule import FooClass", instead I use "from PyQt5 import FooModule", but I do it to purpose for a basic reason: I want to save space so that my implementation is what stands out. The design criteria are often subjective and dependent on the implementation, unless they tell me that the implementation is bad and consider that my other reasons are minor then I will change them.

Comment: @DennisJensen Also I do not pretend to be a model of programming style, each one makes the decision to do it, I will only be responsible for it when I expressly indicate it. In my SW I always enable the sys.argv so that the user can customize certain features of Qt, and the same Qt offers for their SW, if you want to test Qt Designer with: `qtdesigner -style your.qss`